# PHP Coding making different Iframe codes appear

Tags: php, iframe

Hello so I have this code here `<iframe frameborder="0" height="550" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" src="http://example.com/signup.php" width="1000"></iframe>` now I was wondering is there any way to make a php script that can choose a random iframe code and display the php script on the page for example

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="550" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" src="website1.com/signup.php" width="1000"></iframe>

<iframe frameborder="0" height="550" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" src="website2.com/signup.php" width="1000"></iframe>
```

like in website 1 and 2 but have it so each time a person loads that page it switches from site 1 to site 2 and embeds the php or is that n

Comment: How might I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this easily. Try adding the sites to an array like this:

$sites = array(
    'site1.com', 
    'site2.com', 
    'site3.com', 
    'site4.com', 
    'site5.com', 
    'site6.com', 
    'site7.com'
);

Now you can use features like [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to pick a random entry from the site to show in your `<iframe>`:

```
<?php 
$site_to_use = array_rand($sites);
?>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="550" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" src="<?php echo $sites[$site_to_use]; ?>/signup.php" width="1000"></iframe>
```

Or you could even use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="550" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" src="<?php echo $sites[rand(0, (count($sites - 1)))]; ?>/signup.php" width="1000"></iframe>
```

That avoids the hassles of large `if else` or `switch case`statements.

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/273847)

Comment: You'd add all the html tags you need and all but this does exactly what you need, and whenever you need to add/remove a site, you just do it through the array.

Comment: Hello so I have used your code and embeded the php to my page but nothing shows up and im not sure why I just want to embed the php script